# Tkinter radio button clear / reset values

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am writing a Tkinter program for the first time and have a question on radio buttons. What I am trying to do is this:

1. open a set of images (one at a time).
2. When an image is opened, annotate a value using the radio button.
3. Collect this value in a list

So, in this example I have 2 compounds and the list would have 2 annotations.

The problem I have is, if by mistake the user clicks radiobutton 2 instead of one, and then corrects him/herself, the list will have 4 items (3 for the first image, 1 for the second). How do I handle this, so that the list will have only 2 values?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

cmp_list = ["VU435DR","VU684DR"]

li = []
li_final = []

def sel():
    selection = str(var.get())

    if selection == "1":
        li.append("Antagonist")
    elif selection == "2":        
        li.append("Agonist")

for i in range(len(cmp_list)):
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.IntVar()
    ig = str(cmp_list[i] + '.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(ig))
    panel = tk.Label(root,image=img)
    panel.pack(side = "top",fill="none",expand="no")
    #w = tk.Text(height=2,width=50)
    #w.pack(side='right")

    q = tk.Radiobutton(root,text="Antagonist",command=sel,value=1,variable=var)
    q.pack()

    r = tk.Radiobutton(root,text="Agonist",command=sel,value=2,variable=var)
    r.pack()
    root.mainloop()

print li
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating more than one instance of `tk.Tk()`. This is not how Tkinter was designed to work, and it will yield unpredictable behavior. A proper Tkinter program always has exactly one instance of `tk.Tk()`.

If you need more than one window, for the second and subsequent windows you should create an instance of `tk.Toplevel`.

To answer your specific question about how to handle someone first hitting one radiobutton and then the other -- the problem is that you are unconditionally appending to your list each time they click on a radiobutton. The solution is to use some sort of flag or indicator to know whether one of the radiobuttons has been clicked, or change your code so that it doesn't matter.

Let's look at that second option - make it so it doesn't matter. When you open up a new image you can automatically append a value to your list. In this case, set it to `None` to say that nothing has been picked yet. Then, in `sel`, you would always replace the last element rather than append a new element, since you know that the last element always refers  to the current compound.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply !! Thank you Bryan. I'll have a go at it later today.